# Parse any string number to number

Tags: c#

I'm trying to found out if a string value is any kind of number. The numbers can be anything like $23.23, (232.3434), 34.4545, 64.345, 34.34%

For dollars and percentages I can remove the % and $ symbols from the string, but I can't get this number to get parsed using this code.

```
        string _number = "64.345";

        double _double;

        if (Double.TryParse(_number, NumberStyles.Any, null, out _double))
        {

        }
        else
        {
        }
```

What am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: What is your culture settings for your OS, it likely is misinterpreting the `.`. Does it fix your problem if you passed in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` for the format provider?

Comment: Yes it works. If you retype as answer, I will mark it as answer. My CurrentCulture was different. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your culture settings for your OS, it likely is misinterpreting the `.`.

If you passed in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` for the format provider that should solve your problem. When you pass in null it uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and your PC is set to a culture that does not interpret a `.` as a separator for decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the double.Parse() instead with a try catch statement, like this:

```
string _number = "64.345";

double _double;

try
{
   _double = Double.Parse(_number)
   // Other actions
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
   // Actions for when invalid parameter is given for parse
}
```

Comment: That would be slower than the TryParse, everything that you put in the `catch` could just go in the `else` of the `if` the TryParse is in.